# FireDAC TFDTable.Post vs TFDQuery UPDATE clause commt

Tags: delphi, firedac

Using FireDAC in Delphi 10.2 to a Firebird 2.5 database, seeing a behavior I don't understand.

I open a TFDTable, Locate a desired record, call Edit and update some fields in that record and then call Post.  If, after doing this and while the program is still running and the DB connection open, I open the DB in FlameRobin or other external data viewer and view the table, the changes I posted aren't visible in that external viewer and don't become visible until I close the DB connection as the program terminates.  If I instead use a TFDQuery and normal transaction handling to UPDATE the same fields via SQL statement, the changes become visible in the external viewer immediately after the transaction is committed and I refresh the external view.

TFDTable.CachedUpdates and Exclusive are both False; Fetch, Field and Update options are at defaults; and UpdateObject and UpdateTransaction are unassigned.

What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: So, which behaviour do you want: the FDTable to behave like the FDQuery or vice-versa?  Are you calling ApplyUpdates for both?

Comment: Martyn - I want the TFDTable to behave like the TFDQuery as far as immediate external visibility of changes.  I've tried calling ApplyUpdates, both after each 
Post, and after all in a set of record changes on the same table have been posted - no joy.

Comment: So I never figured this out and just stopped using TFDTable for anything.  But now I'm converting a large body of code from AbsoluteDB to FireDAC/Firebird and which uses TABSTable extensively - in a large majority of the cases, sticking with the table-based code would be *far* easier than rewriting all those areas for queries.  So if anyone has some thoughts, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: I don't use TFDTable so I don't know the specifics but the problem you're describing most likely means there is an active transaction that is only being committed when the database connection closes. Monitor the value of TFDConnection.InTransaction while your program is running and you'll see what I mean.